# How to add an attribute in an input date field

Tags: forms, hooks, datetime

I want add the attribute *autocomplete="Off"* in the input field of the date field.
I've created a modulo with *hook_form_alter* but not works.
This is my code:

```
function no_input_autocomplete_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    if($form_id === 'prenotazione_node_form'){
        $form['field_periodo_prenotazione_to']['#attributes'] = array('autocomplete' => 'Off');
    }
}
```

I've noticed that with other field type works as I expect.

How can solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
$form['field_periodo_prenotazione_to']['widget'][0]['value']['#attributes'] = array('autocomplete' => 'Off');
```

Comment: I've already try this but not works